# Generate random value from a range of number for a fixed limit in python

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray, python-3.8

code:

```
 import random
 import numpy as np
 X=10
 Y=5
 while True:
    random_value=np.random.choice((range(1,X)),Y)
    if sum(random_value)==X:
       break
    else:
       continue
```

Question

This code works fine for small value of X and Y
but it does not work for big values like X=56 and Y= 52.
My aim is to generate random values from X in a list whose size is Y and also the sum of the random value should b X

How should i optimise the code to get output for big values

Comment: DId you compute the probability of choosing 52 times from `[1..55]` that add up to 56? With one element greater than 6, your approach is not feasible.

Comment: what do you mean by 'does not work'?  Some error?

Comment: Exactly what Michael Szczesny said - the code itself is fine; your math is not. If picking 52 numbers whose sum must be 55, at least 50 of the chosen numbers must be 1. If you're trying to obtain such an arrangement randomly, you will be waiting for a very, very long time. Perhaps consider starting with 50 1's and then randomly choosing 2 numbers whose sum is 5?

Comment: yes i need to get 52 random numbers from 56 .Also the sum of those random numbers should be 56.To check that i have added the line if sum(random_value)==X: but as i said since it is a big value it takes a lot of time .is there any other way to do it @MichaelSzczesny

Comment: Yes that is the issue i have to wait a long time .Since these values have to be fed into a signal generator ,the limit should start from 1 .@AJH

Comment: There is no error but it stops it does gives any output .what i understood is,it is iterating over the while loop till the condition is fullfilled.@hpaulj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some working code. In a case like `X = 56` and `Y = 52`, most of the numbers will be ones, so this code figures out how many 1s are needed, generates the other numbers, and then subtracts from or adds to those random numbers until they sum to the needed sum.

```
import numpy as np
import random

def get_vals_from_X_Y(X, Y):
    # If X = 56 and Y = 55, can have a single 2 in generated values and then 54 ones.
    # If X = 56 and Y = 54, can have 2 twos and 52 ones.
    # Pattern is that you need (Y - (X - Y)) ones, which simplifies to (2Y - X).
    # This pattern ONLY APPLIES if Y >= X / 2. If Y < X / 2, then every Y value needs to be >= 2.

    if Y >= X / 2:
        num_1s_needed = 2*Y - X
    else:
        num_1s_needed = 0
    
    # vals will eventually contain Y values summing to X.
    vals = []
    vals = [1]*num_1s_needed

    # What the random numbers need to sum to. It's X minus all the ones.
    sum_needed = X - num_1s_needed
    
    if sum_needed == 0:
        return vals
    elif sum_needed == 1:
        idx = random.randrange(num_1s_needed-1)
        vals.insert(idx, 1)
        return vals
    else:
        # places_left determines how many random numbers to generate.
        places_left = Y - num_1s_needed
        random_vals = [random.randrange(1, sum_needed) for i in range(places_left)]
        
        # If sum of random_vals is too small, add randomly to a value as needed.
        while sum(random_vals) < sum_needed:
            idx_to_add_to = random.randrange(len(random_vals))
            if random_vals[idx_to_add_to] < X:
                random_vals[idx_to_add_to] += 1
        
        # Sort from big to small and find the first instance of 1.
        # Add all 1s to vals and remove from random_vals.
        # Adjust sum_needed to always be X - len(vals).

        random_vals.sort(reverse=True)
        try:
            idx_1 = random_vals.index(1)
            orig_length = len(random_vals)
            random_vals = random_vals[:idx_1]
            vals += [1]*(orig_length - len(random_vals))
            sum_needed -= (orig_length - len(random_vals))

        # If there is no 1 in random_vals, function will go to the except block.
        except:
            pass
        
        # Subtract as needed from a random value that is greater than 1.
        while sum(random_vals) > sum_needed:
            idx_to_subtract_from = random.randrange(len(random_vals))
            if random_vals[idx_to_subtract_from] > 1:
                random_vals[idx_to_subtract_from] -= 1
        
        # Generate a random index and insert each random_val into vals at that index.
        for i in range(len(random_vals)):
            idx = 0
            if len(vals) > 1:
                idx = random.randrange(len(vals))
            vals.insert(idx, random_vals[i])
        return vals

# Change X and Y to your liking.
vals = get_vals_from_X_Y(X, Y)
```

Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @AJH.

Answer (score 0):

You can sample from a suitable [multinomial distribution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html), but the given range `[1..limit-1]` will usually not be exhausted in the result, even if it were possible.

```py
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

N     = 52
limit = 56
a = rng.multinomial(limit - N, np.full(N, 1.0/N)) + 1

print(a)
print(f'sum:{a.sum()}, length:{a.shape[0]}')
```

Output (random)

```
[1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
sum:56, length:52
```